# $A$-invariant subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$.
Let the minimal polynomial of $A$ be $\prod_{i=1}^m q_i(x)^{\ell_i}$, where each $q_i(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is monic irreducible, each $\ell_i>0$, and gcd$(q_i(x),q_j(x))=1$ for $i \neq j$. If $s=\deg q_1(x)^{\ell_1}$, does there exist a $v \in \mathbb{F}^n$ such that $\lbrace v, Av, ..., A^{s-1}v \rbrace$ is linearly independent?

I am aware that the above is true when $m=1$. But what if $m>1$?

Comment: Try looking for Frobenius decomposition theorem, the steps of the proof need this result so it is most likely that you will find it in any linear algebra book. Also try reasoning on $\ker (q_1(x)^{l_1})$

Comment: Thank you for the help @julio_es_sui_glace :)